# IE 11 Slower running Angular Application than IE 10

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

WE have a monolithic AngularJS application, and the other day, the owner, who inexplicably uses IE comes to me and shows me that the Application in slower using the SPA model than it was using the old page model.

I did a bunch of research, and then I finally set up an IE 10 machine next to an IE 11 machine, the machine running IE 11 being a Dell workstation with a newer quad core XEON, and the IE 10 machine being an old off lease Lenovo with a C2D, and astonishingly, the machine running IE10 was faster loading views than the IE11 machine, often considerably.

Has anyone else run into this and possibly come up with any solutions, aside from "Don't Use IE"?

Comment: You're probably better off [opening an issue in their repository](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/new) for discussion. Your question is too broad to fit here.

Comment: At this point I don't see enough evidence that it is actually IE that is to blame. For all I know the faster machine is severely penalized in other ways. Malware, power settings, badly installed drivers so I/O performance is poor, wonky network settings, poor WIFI connection, etc. etc. The sky is the limit.

Comment: I have the same problem, have found the reason why?